# How to exclude email addresses from a specific domain and extract the others pythonically

Tags: python, regex, list

I have a list of email addresses with some from relevant domains and others from spam/irrelevant email domains. I want to capture both these but in separate lists. I know where the relevant ones come from (always the same domain - `@gmail.com` but the spam is from different ones and all of them need to be captured).

```
    # Extract all email ids from a JSON file
    import re
    import json

     with open("test.json", 'r') as fp:
         json_decode = json.loads(fp.read())

         line = str(json_decode)

         match = re.findall(r'[\w\.-]+@[\w.-]+', line)
         l = len(match)
         print(match)

         for i in match:
             domain = match.split('@')[i]


        OUTPUT: match = ['image001.png@01D36CD8.2A2219D0', 'arealjcl@countable.us', 'taylor.l.ingram@gmail.com']
```

The first two are spam and the third is the legitimate email so they have to be in different lists. Do I split at `@` to determine the domain or exclude everything that is not `@gmail.com` and dump in another list.

Comment: both of those options seem like valid approaches, no?

Comment: `DO I split at '@' to determine the domain or exclude everything that is not '@gmail.com' and dump in another list.` : did you try either of those? if you did did either work?

Comment: When I split at '@' (like above), I get a Type Error and it looks like I can't split list objects so I converted to string but that doesn't split it either. Hence I was stuck and wondering whether I was following a proper approach

Comment: Do not split at '@'. It requires more steps to analyze the end of the string which aren't needed. @Siddharth Dushantha's solution is more to the point with minimal extra work. You'll just need to determine how you want to return the two separate lists. Might even declare 2 blank arrays then depending on whether the endswith() fails add to array 1, and if not add to array 2

Comment: @FailSafe Agree, thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recomend you use the `endswith()` function. Here is how you could use it:

```
legit = []
spam = []

# We iterate through the list of matches
for email in match:

    # This checks if the email ends with @gmail.com.
    # If it returns True, that means it is a good email.
    # But, if it returns False, then it means that the email
    # is spam.
    email_status = email.endswith("@gmail.com")


    if email_status == False:
        spam.append(email)

    else:
        legit.append(email)
```

**EDIT:** Changed the code, so that it properly answers your question

Comment: THANK YOU so much for solving my problem with such an incredibly simple answer!

Answer (score 0):

When you split the email addresses on `'@'` you get a two item list:

```
In [3]: 'image001.png@01D36CD8.2A2219D0'.split('@')
Out[3]: ['image001.png', '01D36CD8.2A2219D0']
```

If you want to inspect the *domain* index the second item of the result:

```
In [4]: q = 'image001.png@01D36CD8.2A2219D0'.split('@')

In [5]: q[1]
Out[5]: '01D36CD8.2A2219D0'
```

So your for loop would be more like:

```
In [9]: for thing in match:
   ...:     domain = thing.split('@')[1]
   ...:     print(domain)
   ...:     
01D36CD8.2A2219D0
countable.us
gmail.com
```

Answer (score 0):

you can separate them to two lists by defined relevant domains

```
 # extract all email ids from a json file
 import re
 import json

 relevant_domains = ['@gmail.com'] # you can add more

 with open("test.json", 'r') as fp:
     json_decode = json.loads(fp.read())

     line = str(json_decode)

     match = re.findall(r'[\w\.-]+@[\w.-]+', line)
     l = len(match)
     print(match)

     relevant_emails = []
     spam_emails = []

     for email in match:
         domain = email.split('@')[1]

         if domain in relevant_domains:
             relevant_emails.append(email)
         else:
             spam_emails.append(email)
```